# Ellipsoidal coordinates line element

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

I was told that the line element in ellipsoidal coordinates is:
$$ds^2=a^2(u^2+v^2)\bigg(\frac{du^2}{u^2+1}+\frac{dv^2}{1-v^2}\bigg)+a^2(u^2+1)(1-v^2)d\phi^2$$

I've been trying to obtain this using $ds^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$, and the coordinate [transformation from cartesian to ellipsoidal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfocalEllipsoidalCoordinates.html) given by:

$$\begin{align}
x^2 &= (a^2+\xi)(a^2+\eta)(a^2+\zeta)/(b^2-a^2)(c^2-a^2)\\
y^2 &= (b^2+\xi)(b^2+\eta)(b^2+\zeta)/(a^2-b^2)(c^2-b^2)\\
z^2 &= (c^2+\xi)(c^2+\eta)(c^2+\zeta)/(a^2-c^2)(b^2-c^2).
\end{align}$$

The problem is that I don't recover the same line element and I can't find any source of how to calculate this $ds^2$. I think maybe they just used a simplified version of these coordinates or maybe they named the coordinates wrong. Anyone can identify such line element? or there is any subtlety for calculating it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just find the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$. Let $\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3$ be the coordinates to which you are trying to transform, and let $x_1,x_2,x_3=x,y,z$. Then, the entries of the metric tensor are given by

\begin{align}
g_{\mu\nu}=\sum_\alpha\frac{\partial\xi_\alpha}{\partial x_\mu}\frac{\partial\xi_\alpha}{\partial x_\nu}.
\end{align}

You should get a $3\times 3$ matrix. Then, the line element in ellipsoidal coordinates is given by

\begin{align}
ds^2=\sum_\mu\sum_\nu g_{\mu\nu}dx_{\mu} dx_{\nu}.
\end{align}